# How to create sections?

Tags: theming

I am new to Drupal and I try viewing it as an HTML/CSS website. What I would like to do is have multiple sections(containers) with different backgrounds and content one after the other.
Something similar to this example:  https://figopetinsurance.com/new-figo-pet-cloud-mobile-app.
Or just image 3 containers with different backgrounds and content from each-other that have their CSS class for styling.

Problem is that I am not sure exactly how to achieve that. I have created a basic website with a theme and tried creating a block and styling the theme from CSS. Even though it works it is not practical because for every page I have to create a new block.

Comment: It sounds like you probably want to take a look at using "structured modular content" via either the Paragraphs or ECK modules to start. I'd go with Paragraphs but there's probably multiple different ways to do this. I wrote a blog post and created a video for this using ECK but you can do the same thing with Paragraphs which has a much bigger community and support team. https://www.dannyenglander.com/blog/drupal-8-architecture-video-tour-designing-structured-modular-content-using-entity-construction

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about implementing a functionality or a layout seen in a site, for which just a description of the feature, a screenshot, or a link is provided.